# Show limit to zero for $\frac{x^3-xy^2}{\vert x \vert + y^2}$ does not exist

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Given is the following function $f(x,y)= \frac{x^3-xy^2}{\vert x \vert + y^2}$. How to proof that the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist?

I have yet tried approaching zero in various directions, yet I have not been able to find two with different outcomes.

Comment: with $y=0$ set $x\to0^{\pm}$ gives two values.

Comment: @MyGlasses $0=0$ are the same value. ;-))

Comment: Possibly test the limit as $x\to0$ and $y\to0$ seperate? Does saying $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ imply they are converging at the same rate?

Comment: @NickPavini It implies no such thing. But this limit does exist.

Comment: @Omry I was just brainstorming :)

Comment: @Dr.MV I saw it :) I was contemplating on doing this in a polar way, but that's easier than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you cannot solve it is the fact that the limit exists and is $0$:

$$0 \le \left| \frac {x^3 -xy^2} {|x| + y^2} \right| = \frac {|x^3 -xy^2|} {|x| + y^2} \le \frac {|x^3| + |xy^2|} {|x| + y^2} \le \frac {|x^3| + |xy^2|} {|x|} = |x^2| + |y^2| \to 0 ,$$

which shows (by the sandwich theorem) that

$$\left| \frac {x^3 -xy^2} {|x| + y^2} \right| \to 0 ,$$

whence

$$\frac {x^3 -xy^2} {|x| + y^2} \to 0 .$$

Answer (score 3):

The limit is $0$.  To see this, we note that if $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le 1$, then $|x|+y^2\ge x^2+y^2$.

Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x^3-xy^2}{|x|+y^2}\right|&\le \frac{|x|\,|x^2-y^2|}{x^2+y^2}\\\\
&\le \frac{|x|(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\\\\
&=|x|
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: hmm how do we notice that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le1$?

Comment: @NickPavini You are taking the limit in which they approach zero.

Comment: @NickPavini As $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\to 0$.

Comment: Oh ok. You factored a bit? And used some basic limit properties?

Comment: @NickPavini Which part of the solution do you not understand?

Comment: I dont understand how you isolated the square root, and I dont understand why you put everything in absolute value. I do not mean to be difficult so if I am too lost for this then by all means dont feel inclined to give me a whole lesson lol :)

Comment: @NickPavini If $|x|\le 1$, then $|x|\ge x^2$ and hence $|x|+y^2\ge x^2+y^2$.  And the absolute values ensures that the term of interest doesn't "runaway to the left with negative values.

Comment: Ohh because they are converging at $0$? So $x$ and $y$ will be less than 1? I think I see it thank you:)

Comment: @NickPavini Well done!  You have it now.